# IE doesn't download clientaccesspolicy when run silverlight app from visual studio

Tags: internet-explorer-9, silverlight-5.0

My silverlight application makes requests to wcf-service on remote host that uses SSL.

When I run the application from visual studio (using F5) IE with start page opens. As soon as I make the first request to wcf-service I get CommunicationException (related to cross-domain policy). If I refresh browser's page everything works ok.

Looks like IE can't download clientaccesspolicy.xml before I refresh browser's page at least 1 time.
[image]

But this file is on the server and I can download it using the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using IIS + custom SSL certificate (instead of Web Development Server). It seems that the port used for wcf and the web app that hosts silverlight app must be the same.